# Where to get the .java files of a netbeans project?

Tags: java, netbeans

As you might notice, I'm quite new to netbeans and programming in general.

I've been working on a small project (homework) and now I need the .java files from one of the packages. When I build the project, i get a .jar archive with all the classes. When I compile the package I need, I get a .jar archive of the .class files of this package (in the "build" folder of the project). However, I need a zip archive of the .java files of this package. I'm a little embarassed to ask, but where do I get these from?

Thanks,
Zhao Nan

Comment: then simply get the .java files and zip them. Why do you expect to have the .java files in the .jar file?

Comment: Usually that's in the "src" directory. Compress that directory and it's done. And if it is a maven project you can ask it to generate this for you by running the target "source:jar".

Comment: There is no "src" folder in the project directory. I should have mentioned that. And it is not a maven project.

Comment: So you build a Java project, and are unable to determine where the Java files you're compiling are?

Comment: Exactly. "A little embarassed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Projects` window `(Window-->Projects)` or `Ctri-1`

Navigate to the .java file you want, and right-click on it, and select `Properties`. The path to the file is shown under `All Files`.

To see the path to the project `right-click` on the name of the project (in the `Projects` window), select `Properties`, and the project folder is shown under `Sources-->Project Folder`

Answer (score 3):

If your are on windows, usually if you let netbeans create all by it self it creates a directory called

```
NetbeansProjects
```

Under "documents"

There will be a folder list of all your projects. Under the project name that interest you, go in the "src" folder. All your java files should be there.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 using NetBeans IDE 8.2, a folder called NetBeansProjects was created in my root directory, parallel to the netbeans-8.2 directory. I'm guessing that this was suggested at installation time and can be configured differently.