# Java: Nothing will read in this file

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io, java.util.scanner, filereader

Before I start, I'd like to say that I've spent 4 hours today, 6 hours yesterday and 3 hours before that researching this issue. I've read every post I can find, followed every instruction to the letter, restarted my project, reinstalled my IDE (Netbeans) and even fresh installed my OS, and I haven't found a single piece of helpful advice, so I figured I needed to ask for help.

**AND YES, I HAVE PUT THE FILE IN THE RIGHT LOCATION**
... As a matter of fact, I've put the file in EVERY location. There's a copy in every folder inside my project and also a copy in the overall Projects folder, and also in My Documents. I've checked and changed and defaulted the root directory many times. PLEASE don't tell me to just use an exception handler. The file the program reads in is guaranteed to exist and contain something.

So here's my question:
I'm trying to input and read from a file, however, the result is always that the file can't be found. Here's an example of my code (and it really is down to this atm):

```
package project2;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Here are two of the errors I get (I also get Filenotfound errors, but I don't think I need to add that):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source 
code - unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or 
declared to be thrown
    at project2.Project2.main(Project2.java:14)
C:\Users\jarre\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: 
Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at project2.Project2.main(Project2.java:24)
C:\Users\jarre\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: 
Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

That's it. The file name comes from the arguments, and I have tried every possible variation of the name. I have tried naming the file outside of the arguments, as just the file name itself and also with an explicit file path.

Using a scanner won't let me read anything in. FileReader won't even run.

The text file has no special formatting or characters, and I've used the one I was supplied with and multiple that I hand typed just in case there was an issue with the one I was given. I have also made sure that ".txt" is never read or used twice (I keep my extensions on, anyway).
I have checked attributes and permissions of all files and the Netbeans program itself. I've also made sure that the text files were included in the project build.

I am not using any additional code right now, as I can't do anything until I'm sure that I can read in a file, and then output one as well. I also know that the text files aren't corrupt because I can read them in Python just fine, however, I have to use Java and I have to use Netbeans.

This is a new problem for me, I've always been able to read in files fine, and I've exhausted my options. I really need some help if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` means exactly what it says. Before trying to access the file, print out the fully qualified path and validate the file is _actually_ where you are trying to read it from, because obviously, it is not. `File f = new File(args[0]); System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: Done that already. The path I'm using shows up along with the correct file. I mean it when I say that I put a copy of the file in every folder and subfolder, just in case.

Comment: Please share the command you are using to invoke your application, along with the output of my above request. Does the path have spaces? Special characters? Do you have proper privileges to seek to this location?

Comment: C:\Users\jarre\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project2\crazy.txt

I'm running it in my IDE, and no, I don't think anything contains any kind of weird or special character.

Comment: The first thing to try is to rule out sources of issue. Can you try and run the application directly from command like and see if it works as expected: "javac Project2.java" followed by "java Project2 C:\Users\jarre\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project2\crazy.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first exception (`java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source 
code`) is thrown because the code that you have shown us is not valid java source code.

`new FileReader(args[0])` is declared as throwing `FileNotFoundException` and according to the rules of the java language you either have to catch this exception or declare your main method as throwing this exception.

One way to fix this problem is to write your main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(args[0]);
}
```

---

It seems that you have solved this issue because the second exception (`java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`) is thrown by the `Scanner.nextLine()` method if you try to read past the end of the file.

Since you have not shown any code using the `Scanner` class it's hard to tell where to problem is in this case.

---

> As a matter of fact, I've put the file in EVERY location. There's a copy in every folder inside my project and also a copy in the overall Projects folder, and also in My Documents.

Don't do that. You are creating a mess with files that will be hard to cleanup. If you want to know which file your program is reading then adding the following simple line tells you the exact path and filename:

```
System.out.println(new File(args[0]).getAbsolutePath());
```

---

Have you ever tried with a simple, minimal example like this:

```
package project2;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new File(args[0]).getAbsolutePath());
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(args[0]);
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(inputFile)) {
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(s.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should print out the name of your file with the complete path and then the contents of the file line by line.

Comment: I appreciate the input. The first thing I did was declare the method as throwing this exception, and it still says that the file could not be found.
The problem lies in that the error shouldn't be coming up in the first place

Comment: @Jarbcd have you tried printing out the file name and path as suggested? (`System.out.println(new File(args[0]).getAbsolutePath());`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Java is messing around with you a not found file is a not found file, please elaborate more in this issue by screens of files and directories you are working on.

I would like you to consider take a look at the following:

1. [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)
2. [Path of projects on Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584993/where-to-get-the-java-files-of-a-netbeans-project)

I hope this helps may the code be with you.

Comment: I appreciate the input. The file exists in every possible subfolder, so there's no way it's as simple as "it's just not there". I'm afraid I'm out right now, but when I get back, I'll share screenshots of what I mean.

Comment: Okay please comment here once you get the screenshots so I can get notified.

Answer (score 0):

This reads a file with no problem.  I'll assume you're running JDK 8.

```
/**
 * Read a file example
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 4/21/2017
 * Time: 7:48 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529600/java-nothing-will-read-in-this-file
 */

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Project2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
                bufferedReader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: Project2 <file>");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the input file I used:

```
line1
line2
hello, michael
line 4
```

Here's the output I got:

```
java Project2 .\src\main\resources\test.txt
line1
line2
hello, michael
line 4

Process finished with exit code 0
```